# Visual studio 2012 TDS project not loading in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, sitecore, sitecore8, tds

Visual studio 2012 TDS project not loading in VS2015.showing incompatible.
My scproj file TargetFrameworkVersion is 2.0.

Please let me know if anyone face this kind of issue.How i can resolve this.

Thanks in advance!!
Regards,
Pushpendra

Comment: Do you see any specific messages? Any possibilities to create another project and import all code files into that?

Comment: project itself not loading showing incompatible.

Answer (score 4):

Hedgehog TDS have separate version integrations for each VS version. When you install it, it ask you about integration in different versions of Visual Studio.

You should re-install TDS(and tick VS 2015 compatibility) for ability to use TDS project with VS 2015.

Update:
Following your comment it looks like you don't have TDS at all. (Initially I thought that you don't have TDS for VS 2015). You should go http://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Download and download installer.

Comment: i am new in TDS. Can i know i can reinstall using nuget or some other place.Please guide me if you have idea.

Comment: no, you can't do it with nuget package. It is VS extension. You should go to http://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Download download installer and install it.

Comment: There's no checkbox. Within the download there are separate installers for each versionof VS .

Comment: @jammykam ok, probably I muddle it with some other tool or previous version. But is the same: you should install right extension for your version of VS.

Comment: Most likely confused it with Resharper :D